# Revert IntelliJ IDEA font to pre-2020.1 default font

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, default

I upgraded to IntelliJ 2020.1, which uses the new JetBrains Mono font by default. However, I would like to switch back to using the previous default, but I don't remember the name. What was the name of the default font on pre-2020.1 versions of IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There is an [official comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007965440-How-to-put-the-editor-appearance-back-to-the-previous-version-?page=1#community_comment_360001564299) on the IntelliJ support site, stating the pre-2020.1 defaults per operating system are as follows:

- Mac OS: `Menlo`
- Linux: `DejaVu Sans Mono`
- Windows: `Consolas`
- Fallback: `Monospaced`

I checked the default settings on IDEA version 2019.3 on OSX, and the default font is indeed `Menlo`, Size `12`, Line spacing `1.2`.

You can configure it by going to <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Editor</kbd>  → <kbd>Font</kbd>

Comment: you save my eyes, people need time to familiar with the new font

Comment: Messed up both my shortcuts and the fonts, until I found this. Beware of upgrading to 2020.1.

Comment: For me, the previous font pretty surely was **Consolas**, point 13. But who knows. Bad move by PhpStorm

Comment: According to IntelliJ's blog the new font was designed to be better for coding (https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2020/01/15/jetbrains-mono-a-new-font-made-for-developers/), but just the second day I had trouble debugging something until I realized I had mistaken a 0 for an 8 due to the new font.

Comment: @RicardovandenBroek try 08O (zero, eight, capital o), their capital o is really like 0 shape, thin and high

Comment: @RicardovandenBroek I spent years upon years with the same font. IDE is almost a continuation of my hands and nerves. I can't have it changed. I am not compatible with different fonts. I think the font must remain exactly the same no matter what. At least it should be easy to choose that way.

Comment: I think that Manlo is one of the best font to use with PyCharm.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest option is to do <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>Color Schema</kbd> -> <kbd>Color Scheme Font</kbd>

And choose "Classic Light".  It will revert Font back to Menlo, size 12 and line spacing 1.2

Comment: Thank God. I updated and it was all so different I couldn't continue working. I think I will die of a heart attack because of these guys who think they can just change IDE appearance.

Comment: I wonder why didn't make the switch optional -- at least when upgrading an existing installation.